# API documentation for Okuma control

Tags: api, documentation, okuma

So far I've learned that the controllers (NCs) on Okuma machine tools are windows based and that anyone can write programs that interface with the machine though what is known as the "THINC_API". Where can I find documentation on this API publicly available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be installed along with the API. Look in the start menu under

Start | Programs | Okuma | THINC-API

The screenshot here is of a machining center but if you have a lathe, it should be in the same location too.[image: Start Menu path to Okuma THINC-API Documentation]

Comment: The computer I'm working on right now doesn't have the API installed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Right now documentation isn't made available to download by itself. You can contact your distributor or Okuma to get a copy. The API can be installed on a PC but you won't be able to run applications using it. (they'll error out when you try to instantiate the main API object)

Comment: It's available now -> [https://bitbucket.org/okuma/open-api-sdk](https://bitbucket.org/okuma/open-api-sdk)

Comment: SDK has moved --> https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK